# How to make computer use VPN only?

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I'm using VPN for increased online security but whenever the VPN server fails the connection for some seconds, some application fall back to the original connection and can reveal my real IP.

My OS is Windows 7 and I've found [this tutorial](http://practicalrambler.blogspot.com/2011/01/windows-7-firewall-how-to-always-use.html), but using some third party components may theoretically work after they are started and before that some connections can already be made, e.g. if bittorrent start first, and that's what I'm trying to avoid. I'd like not to use windows firewall for this task, as it seems to be an overkill.

Is there a way to change main connection settings so that it is only used for VPN? Or is there a way to solve the problem on the router level? I have a basic Asus router sharing internet between different PC.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear some answers about this too. I'm increasingly concerned about online privacy and would like to connect to the outside world with a VPN. Is there a noticeable network performance hit that I would have to accept? Why isn't everybody doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to configure your router to allow outbound traffic only to the IP address(es) that support the VPN you're connecting to.

Windows will be unable to access the internet when the VPN connection is down and will resume normal network operation when the VPN goes online.